# Getting error of libQt5WebKit.so.5 while using make command

Tags: python, c++, qt5, archlinux, qtwebkit

I am using **"make"** command and getting errors.

errors are listed below. There are a lot of errors, but I mansion some of them.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.71, needed by /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.71, needed by /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.71, needed by /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.71, needed by /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to `ubrk_open_71'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_close_71'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to `udat_open_71'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_setAttribute_71'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_strcollIter_71'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_reset_71'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_setFromUCallBack_71'
```

Also attached image of the errors.
[image]

Below is the version for Qmake and Qt

[image]

A small suggestion might help me.